# How to design a table using the key names of Json value in Data table

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

So I have a table which holds json data ,I want to show those data in tabular form using Datables.

The problem is the column name should be taken from the key of the json ,
Ill be getting json like this

sql = select data from data_storage where layout id =1

```
{"text-1488375965148":"Rohan","textarea-1488376086684":"Some addresse","top-search":"","text-1488375966552":"rohan@gmail.com"}

{"text-1488375965148":"Vikram","textarea-1488376086684":"Hello hello hello","top-search":"","text-1488375966552":"vikrambanand@gmail.com"}

{"text-1488375965148":"Ruchita","textarea-1488376086684":"bangalore","top-search":"","text-1488375966552":"Ruchita@gmail.com"}
```

As you can see the format of the json for the above query is same so I want to show them in tabular form where the table should like this .

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>text-1488375965148</th>
      <th>textarea-1488376086684</th>
      <th>text-1488375966552</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea how I can achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop your JSON data and append data to table:

```js
var jsonData = [{
    "text-1488375965148": "Rohan",
    "textarea-1488376086684": "Some addresse",
    "top-search": "",
    "text-1488375966552": "rohan@gmail.com"
  },

  {
    "text-1488375965148": "Vikram",
    "textarea-1488376086684": "Hello hello hello",
    "top-search": "",
    "text-1488375966552": "vikrambanand@gmail.com"
  },

  {
    "text-1488375965148": "Ruchita",
    "textarea-1488376086684": "bangalore",
    "top-search": "",
    "text-1488375966552": "Ruchita@gmail.com"
  }
];

var head = $('table thead');
var body = $('table tbody');
var row = '';

row += '<tr>';
$.each(jsonData[0], function(k, v) {
  row += '<th>' + k + '</th>';
});
row += '</tr>';

head.append(row);


$.each(jsonData, function() {
  row = '<tr>';
  $.each(this, function(k, v) {
    row += '<td>' + v + '</td>';
  });
  row += '</tr>';

  head.append(row);
})
```

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```